# URL latex linebreak

Tags: latex, line-breaks

When a URL is over a line and goes onto a second line, the hyperlink only uses the first line. Is there a way to get around this and yet still have the URL on multiple lines?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54946/how-to-break-long-url-in-an-item

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should use the `url` package:

```
\usepackage{url}
...
\url{http://long.url.com/...     .../stuff}
```

and it will break it for you at an appropriate place.

Comment: The url package will break the line at slashes, but it will not break long directory or file names, such as generated with some blogging software. Anyone have tips on how to fix this subproblem? Inserting '\-' for optional hyphenation does not work within a \url macro.

Comment: A few moments later, I found http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=4022, which prompted me to add the [hyphens] option to the url package. This fixed my problem

Comment: If your line wraps are ok, but your links are broken (i.e., the href is only using the first line), then try using the `hyperref` package instead of the `url` package. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @Paul Your comment should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Make sure you use `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` and *not* `\usepackage{url}[hyphens]`!

Answer (score 48):

I suggest using package:

```
\usepackage{xurl}
```

This works fine for me on overleaf.

Example:

```
\url{https://www.tudelft.nl/ewi/over-de-faculteit/afdelingen/intelligent-systems/pattern-recognition-bioinformatics/pattern-recognition-laboratory/data-and-software/dd-tools/}
```

Answer (score 18):

At the preamble, just put `\usepackage{breakurl}` somewhere after `\usepackage{hyperref}`. The `\burl` command is defined and, by default, the package also turns the `\url` command into a synonym of `\burl`.

Comment: This worked for me sometimes, but not others: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54946/how-to-break-long-url-in-an-item

Comment: Seems a better answer than the previous one, as it works with pdfannotextractor.pl (at least on my experiments)

Comment: FWIW, `breakurl` only works with the `dvips` driver, NOT with `pdflatex`. See [CTAN docs](https://ctan.org/pkg/breakurl?lang=en).

Answer (score 15):

Do it the following way. You are good to go!

```
\begin{document}
\sloppy
```

Comment: this is the only thing that helped me!

Comment: This really the Slegdehammer version of fixing this problem. While `\sloppy` can be helpful in very selected instances, a global activation of it is really discouraged

Answer (score 9):

For me only this worked:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

and with this code to add line breaks after every normal alphabetic character and with *-~'":

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks% save the current one
  \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
  \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
  \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
  \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
  \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
  \do\Y\do\Z\do\*\do\-\do\~\do\'\do\"\do\-}%
```

answer complited from this site:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url/10401

Comment: Positive even in the bib with plain url `url={http://..}` that is without having to enclose with `\url{}`. On some occasion it should be sufficient to write `\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks\do\*\do\-\do\~\do\'\do\"\do\-}`

Answer (score 4):

What packages (hyperref,url) and drivers (pdftex, dvips, etc.) are you using?  Are you using the [breaklinks](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-60003.2) option to hyperref?

According to the [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=breaklinks) you might want to try the `breakurl` package, though it appears you may simply be out of luck in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

What worked best for me (with pdflatex) was

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
```

and then just `\url{http://stackoverflow.com/}` to create URLs. It only broke URLs at `.` and `/`, which was okay for my document. Importantly, other approaches I tried created PDFs where only the first line of the URL was a clickable link, and the destination URL was truncated to this portion, which is pretty confusing and bad.

Answer (score 0):

Long URLs that contain underscores (_) in path segments will not be broken when using `\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}`. However, I found that I could solve this problem by manually breaking lines in the displayed label using `\\\\`, like this:

```
\href{http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Nick\_Brooks2/publication/220012411\_Cultural\_responses\_to\_aridity\_in\_the\_Middle\_Holocene\_and\_increased\_social\_complexity/links/0922b4f398ad68bc96000000.pdf}{http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Nick\_Brooks2/publication/220012411\_\\Cultural\_responses\_to\_aridity\_in\_the\_Middle\_Holocene\_and\_increased\_social\_\\complexity/links/0922b4f398ad68bc96000000.pdf}
```

This results in URLs that are a bit prettier (IMO) than the use of `\usepackage{breakurl}` and `\burl`, as suggested by Debajyoti Mondal, and allows you to display the full URL if you wish.

Answer (score -2):

There is a simple answer. Use \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} before \begin{document}